# Excel web addin : Is it possible to enable or disable contextual menu items at runtime?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

I'm working on an Excel add-in using the JavaScript APIs.

Is it possible to enable/disable or to change visibility **right-click** contextual menu items at runtime ?

Comment: Have you seen this article in the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands

Comment: I think the article talks about the ribbon contextual tab, but what I need is enable/disable **right-click** contextual menu items